# Align origin and axis to custom vertices

Tags: origin, axis

Let's say you have some vertices which are places randomly in space.
You want the origins to be aligned based on these vertices. I struggled a lot with it previously
so I want to share the easy method I found.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

1. In Edit mode select right vertices.
2. Go to Transform Orientation - Plus icon to create new orientation based on your selection

[image]

3. Back to Object Mode check ‘Origins’ box

[image]

4. In Object Mode use ‘Align to Transform Orientation’ operation

[image]

5. Enjoy!

[image]

I hope it was useful! Happy holidays everyone!