# How do you rotate the local axes of an object?

Tags: modeling

I've got an object whose local axes are not pointing the right way. Is it possible to correct the orientation of these axes?. This object has a pretty weird positioning and I would like to be able to move it on its own axes.
[image]

Comment: There are quite a few answers to this on BSE, like this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/206201/35559, although actually a web-wide search on 'blender align origin' gets better search results.

Comment: @RobinBetts that's not exactly what I need but thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want that the local axes points like the standard global orientation, you can just go in Object - Apply - rotation

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to fix this. I just have to reset the rotation back to 0 in object mode and rotate the object again in edit mode. The local axes will then point the right way.